# truncate command not working because of foreign constraint but works when using designer mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using Sql Server Management Studio 2008.

When I try to truncate a table using the following command

```
truncate table MyTable
```

it gives me an error saying

> > Cannot truncate table 'dbo.MyTable' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

I know I have a foriegn Key in this table.

Now when I do the following

- Right click on table and select `Edit Top 200 Rows`
- Right on any records from the table
- and hit `Delete`, it gets deleted.

[image]

I am confused with this behaviour, please can some one let me know how and why this happens and how do I delete using truncate statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicly because there is a difference between `DELETE` and `TRUNCATE`

If you could do that even a simple delete would work for those records. (If there is no reference on them, or if an `ON DELETE` statement is declared on the other table which made the reference to MyTable)

```
DELETE FROM dbo.MyTable
```

With the `TRUNCATE` you can't do that. It is more then a `DELETE`. You have to remove the `CONSTRAINT` first and then you can make the Truncate. A Truncate is not allowed on a table which referenced by a forign_key.

And for example an other difference a Truncate command reserts the `IDENTITY` columns as well, but a `DELETE` not.

Here is a good article about it:

[The difference in TRUNCATE and DELETE in Sql Server](http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/05/09/the-difference-in-truncate-and-delete-in-sql-server/)